# Laptop charger 19V 6.32A 120W Adapter as replacement for 20V 7.5A 150W

Tags: laptop, adapter, voltage, charger, undervolting

Is it safe to use 19V 6.32A 120W Laptop Charger / Adapter , because I lost my 20V 7.5A 150W adapter and the only one I could find locally is the 19V 6.32A 120W , currently using the laptop for Gaming and not Rendering (yet)..?

Answer (score 2):

The new power supply is obviously less powerful than the old one. It’s impossible to predict how it will behave.

It might work correctly for normal tasks but you might start noticing your battery will start to drain when gaming. It might also just shut down when needing more power than can be supplied.

Either way, it’s probably better to look for a new power supply that matches the old one in voltage and can deliver at least as much current and/or power.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should look for the same voltage and equal or higher current. Power is simply voltage multiplied by amperage: 20V × 7.5A = 150W.

Electrical devices usually have some tolerance for voltage differences. 15% is usually assumed safe, so your laptop should run fine with anything between 17V and 23V. Still, it would be better to get an exactly 20V one.

Using a slightly less powerful power adapter can be fine sometimes, but I wouldn't recommend it in the long run. Under high CPU and GPU load the adapter may not be capable of delivering that much power and the battery will start to discharge despite laptop being connected to the wall. This are not normal operating circumstances, so it's hard to predict how this would affect hardware's longevity. If it's not a particularly high quality adapter, it can also melt (literally) under load higher than designed, possibly damaging the laptop.

Using this power adapter should be okay for now, but try not to stress it too much and get a more powerful one.